# php try ... else

Tags: php, exception

Is there something similar in PHP to the `try ... else` in Python?

I need to know if the try block executed correctly as when the block executed correctly, a message will be printed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `try { } catch () { }` and `throw`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
try {
    $a = 13/0; // should throw exception
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

or manually:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("I don't want to be tried!");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but he was asking about the `else` block, not exceptions in general...

Comment: Oh, and `$a = 13/0;` will not throw an exception unless you have an error handler installed that throws exceptions (`set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) { throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);});`...  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Comment: Is PHP's "catch" block not equivalent to Python's "else" block?

Comment: @enobrev: No it isn't. See my answer below.

Comment: It's not.  Python uses `except:` as php's `catch` block.  The `else` block is executed ONLY if no exceptions were thrown (the try-bock completed cleanly).  `try: ... except: ... else: ...` http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the clarification!  Besides your response below, I figure one could put what would be inside the `else` block inside the `try` block, although I'm guessing the point here is to test those statements separately.

Comment: @enobrev, the difference is that exceptions thrown in the `else` clause are not caught by the except/catch block.  So a little more logic is required than just placing the else within the try (as my answer tries to communicate)...

Answer (score 62):

PHP does not have try/catch/else. You could however set a variable in the catch block that can be used to determine if it was run:

```
$caught = false;

try {
    // something
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $caught = true;
}

if (!$caught) {

}
```

Comment: This gets full of `$caught = true;` statements if there are several `catch` blocks.

Comment: One minor note, python's else block would only be executed if `$caught` is false, not true...

Answer (score 7):

I think the "else" clause is a bit limiting, unless you don't care about any exceptions thrown there (or you want to bubble those exceptions)...  From my understanding of Python, it's basically the equivalent of this:

```
try {
    //...Do Some Stuff Here
    try {
        // Else block code here
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->elseBlock = true;
        throw $e;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if (isset($e->elseBlock) && $e->elseBlock) {
        throw $e;
    }
    // catch block code here
}
```

So it's a bit more verbose (since you need to re-throw the exceptions), but it also bubbles up the stack the same as the else clause...

**Edit** Or, a bit cleaner version (5.3 only)

```
class ElseException extends Exception();

try {
    //...Do Some Stuff Here
    try {
        // Else block code here
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new ElseException('Else Clasuse Exception', 0, $e);
    }
} catch (ElseException $e) {
    throw $e->getPrevious();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // catch block code here
}
```

**Edit 2**

Re-reading your question, I think you may be overcomplicating things with an "else" block...  If you're just printing (which isn't likely to throw an exception), you don't really need an else block:

```
try {
    // Do Some stuff
    print "Success";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Handle error here
    print "Error";
}
```

That code will only ever print *either* `Success` or `Error`...  Never both (since if the `print` function throws the exception, it won't be actually printed...  But I don't think the `print` CAN throw exceptions...).

Comment: In my case it worked fine putting the next `try{}` inside the `catch{}`

Comment: @ircmaxell Your "Edit 2" answer is a good answer. Maybe post it as a separate answer so that it can be voted up by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with python but it sounds like you're after Try Catch blocks used with exceptions...

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

There is [`try-catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in php.

**Example:**

```
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo 'Hello World';
```

Comment: The question was about php equivalent to python's "try-else", that is having a compact way of executing a block of code after the try block whenever no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $clean = false;
    ...
    $clean = true;
} catch (...) { ... }

if (!$clean) {
    //...
}
```

That's the best you can do.

Comment: You should set $clean to it's initial value before you enter the try..catch block. See webbiedave's answer.

Comment: @jmz Hum? Why? it's indifferent; there's no block scope in PHP.