# Cleanest way to execute code outside of try block only if no exception is thrown

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

This question is about the **best way** to execute code outside of try block only if no exception is thrown.

```
try {
    //experiment
    //can't put code after experiment because I don't want a possible exception from this code to be caught by the following catch. It needs to bubble.
} catch(Exception $explosion) {
    //contain the blast
} finally {
    //cleanup
    //this is not the answer since it executes even if an exception occured
    //finally will be available in php 5.5
} else {
    //code to be executed only if no exception was thrown
    //but no try ... else block exists in php
}
```

This is method suggested by [@webbiedave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364780/863924) in response to the question [php try .. else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3364752/863924). I find it unsatisfactory because of the use of the extra `$caught` variable.

```
$caught = false;

try {
    // something
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $caught = true;
}

if (!$caught) {

}
```

So what is a better (or the best) way to accomplish this without the need for an extra variable?

Comment: Put it in the try block. If it might throw another exception that you don't want caught by the outer try block, then use a nested try-catch to catch that exception. Be mindful that you don't use exceptions as flow control, however.

Comment: @peachykeen That won't work because the exception needs to bubble.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're using exceptions to control execution a bit too much. Are you sure you need both of those blocks throwing and the latter bubbling? It could very well be that the exceptions *should* be replaced by a variable and proper flow-control.

Comment: Seems to me that code needs to go into the try block

Comment: One idea is to put the try block in it's own method. Return false if an exception was cought and return true otherwise. Then you can just do an if(methodThatHandlesException()) { ... }

Comment: @rcapote Add that as an answer as it is a viable alternative.

Comment: @Orangepill It doesn't function correctly in the try block for reasons explained in the question and further in the comments.

Comment: @ogc-nick Just curious as to a use case where this technique would be applicable

Comment: @peachykeen I believe you are right about possibly misusing Exceptions. Unfortunately I do not have the option of changing the design at this point but I have learned something about the limited usefulness of Exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to put the try block in a method, and return false if an exception is cought.

```
function myFunction() {
    try {
        // Code  that throws an exception
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if the exception needs to propagate then just re-throw it in the catch

Comment: I like this better because the `$myFunctionResult` variable that would be assigned tot he return value of `myFunction()` wouldn't be completely arbitrary.

Comment: Yea you could do something similar with exceptions. Inverse exception function lol, something like: if an exception is thrown, return from the function normally. If no exception is cought, throw a new exception. Then the catch($e) { /*Code to run if no exception was cought....wait a second.... */ }. Just really ugly and unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Have your catch block exit the function or (re)throw/throw an exception. You can filter your exceptions as well. So if your other code also throws an exception you can catch that and (re)throw it. Remember that:

1. Execution continues if no exception is caught.
2. If an exception happens and is caught and not (re)throw or a new one throw.
3. You don't exit your function from the catch block.
4. It's **always a good idea** to (re)throw any exception that you don't handle.
5. We should **always be explicit** in our exception handling. Meaning if you catch exceptions check the error that we can handle anything else should be (re)throw(n)

The way I would handle your situation would be to (re)throw the exception from the second statement.

```
try {
    $this->throwExceptionA();
    $this->throwExceptionB();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    if($e->getMessage() == "ExceptionA Message") {
        //Do handle code

    } elseif($e->getMessage() == "ExceptionB Message") {
        //Do other clean-up
        throw $e;

    } else {
        //We should always do this or we will create bugs that elude us because
        //we are catching exception that we are not handling
        throw $e;
    }
}
```