# Issues with try/catch using Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to check if a coupon code is valid in stripe before proceeding with the rest of the calls to their API. If you send them an invalid coupon code for a subscription, you get a fatal error.

So, as a noob, I figured I'd attempt `try/catch`, but clearly I'm messing up something. I'm doing something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['coupon'])) { //see if person even submitted a code

try {

$couponValid = \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve($coupon);

 throw new Exception();//if not a valid coupon code
} catch (Exception \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    echo("error");
}
}
//run the rest of the code if no errors
```

This still gives me fatal errors that the coupon code doesn't exist (which it doesn't).

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: No such coupon: fdsf`

The stripe documentation says to handle errors [like this](https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling) which I'm doing (I think)

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: After your comment, I went and did a little more digging.  Grabbed a copy of the Stripe API and ran some tests myself.  \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest was successfully caught.  I believe the error may be generated by what comes after what you posted here.  Just from what was posted above, if $_POST['coupon'] is empty, its going to pick up at your comment and run whats below.  Is there a Stripe call using the coupon after the code you posted above, that isn't wrapped in it's own try/catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Exception from your catch.

```
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
```

If you need to catch both Exception and \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest You can chain the catches together.

```
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
//Handle Invalid Request
} catch (Exception $e) {
//Handle Exception
}
```

If you are using php 7.1+ And you want the same handling regardless of whats thrown you can pipe them.

```
} catch (Exception | \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gave me the same error. I tried your first suggestion to remove the Exception from my catch

Comment: Odd.  Is there other code on that page making Stripe calls?  I get a feeling that your issue may be in the surrounding code, and not what you have shown.

Comment: Actually, you're onto something. in the part where I have `//run the rest of the code, I use coupon again`. I thought that anything that comes in there will only run if an exception isn't caught. That's the problem. So, how do I stop the code from running if there is an exception?

Comment: What's weird is that the code seems to work fine when I test locally, but not on my server. Does this try/catch work differently for different PHP versions?

Comment: Just off the code you had pasted, the If block it is wrapped in, can skip that entire block of code as long as the post is empty.  Even if it is not empty, and the code inside it runs, If you do not stop the execution somehow when  you catch the exception execution will continue.  So you can very well be catching your first call, and have the second call still run.

Comment: You figured out the problem. Thanks. Would have never gotten there without your suggestion. I ended up using something similar to the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364780/989722